# joda-time Duration.isLongerThan() commutativity

Tags: clojure, jodatime, duration

```
(ns opyt.core
  (:import [org.joda.time Duration]))

(let [d1 (Duration. 1 0)
      d2 (Duration. 0 1)]
  (= (.isLongerThan d1 d2) (.isLongerThan d2 d1)))
```

**(= ... )** in **let** form returns **false**. This is due to simple comparisons of milliseconds in isLongerThan(), but d1 has negative milliseconds and d2 positive.

Is this a bug or feature? Is there any way in joda-time library to compare durations by absolute value?

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with Clojure, really, it's just the behavior of the Joda time library. cf. the [joda time javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/ReadableDuration.html#isLongerThan%28org.joda.time.ReadableDuration%29), this returns `true` only if the duration passed in is equal to the duration compared to. Apparently, there is no absolute value / method provided.

Answer (score 0):

I can't check this, but ...

As @schaueho notes, there is no `abs` method/function for `org.joda.time.Duration`. However, we can concoct one:

```
(ns opyt.core
  (:import [org.joda.time Duration]))

(defn abs [^Duration d]
  (if (.isLongerThan d Duration/ZERO)
    d
    (.negated d)))
```

Then

```
(let [d1 (abs (Duration. 1 0))
      d2 (abs (Duration. 0 1))]
  (= (.isLongerThan d1 d2) (.isLongerThan d2 d1)))
```

... hopefully returns true - because both arguments to `=` are false.

Indeed, we would hope that

```
(.isEqual d1 d2)
```

... would return true in its place.